# Entity Framework 6: Create 0..0:1 mapping where both tables have foreign keys of different types

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, one-to-one

I have a database with the following structure:

```
Create Table Employees
(
    EmployeeId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Name NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    CertificationId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL
);

Create Table Certifications
(
    CertificationId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    EmployeeIssuedToId INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Employees(EmployeeId),
    ExpiryDate DATETIME2 NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE Employees 
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (CertificationId) 
        REFERENCES Certifications(CertificationId);
```

In the database you can have employees who may or may not have a certification but every certification has a corresponding employee.  I have the following EF classes:

```
    public partial class Certification
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid CertificationId { get; set; }

        public int EmployeeIssuedToId { get; set; }
        [Required, ForeignKey("EmployeeIssuedToId")]
        public virtual Employee EmployeeIssuedTo { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
        public DateTime ExpiryDate { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Employee
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Guid? CertificationId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CertificationId")]
        public virtual Certification Certification { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class EmployeeCertificationModel : DbContext
    {
        public EmployeeCertificationModel()
            : base("name=DbConnString")
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Certification> Certifications { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
                .HasOptional(e => e.Certification)
                .WithOptionalDependent(c => c.EmployeeIssuedTo);
        }
    }
```

I then try to execute the following code:

```
        using (var writeContext = new EmployeeCertificationModel())
        {
            var fred = new Employee
            {
                EmployeeId = 1,
                Name = "Fred"
            };
            writeContext.Employees.Add(fred);
            writeContext.SaveChanges();

            fred.Certification = new Certification
            {
                CertificationId = new Guid("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001"),
                EmployeeIssuedToId = fred.EmployeeId,
                ExpiryDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(7)
            };
            writeContext.SaveChanges();
        }
```

However, that results in the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException : The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'EmployeeIssuedTo' on type 'EmployeeCertifications.Certification' is not valid. The foreign key name 'EmployeeIssuedToId' was not found on the dependent type 'EmployeeCertifications.Employee'. The Name value should be a comma separated list of foreign key property names.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Instead of `ForeignKey("EmployeeIssuedToId")` try `ForeignKey("EmployeeId")`

Comment: Following @yadejo's suggestion I get this exception:
`Employee_Certification_Target_Employee_Certification_Source: : The types of all properties in the Dependent Role of a referential constraint must be the same as the corresponding property types in the Principal Role. The type of property 'EmployeeId' on entity 'Employee' does not match the type of property 'CertificationId' on entity 'Certification' in the referential constraint 'Employee_Certification'.`

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend avoiding this non-normalized schema in the first place.  So your first table declaration becomes:

```
Create Table Employees
(
    EmployeeId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Name NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);
```

And you can define the property in your model with an [InverseProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591583(v=vs.113).aspx#Anchor_11) attribute.

```
public partial class Employee
{
    ...

    [InverseProperty("EmployeeIssuedToId")]
    public virtual Certification Certification { get; set; }
}
```